# Kotlin Property Observable

Tags: kotlin, observable, reactiveui, reactivex

In ReactiveUI we can use [`whenAny()`](https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/when-any/) to create observable from property or a group of properties. How can I achieve something similar in Kotlin?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin

Answer (score 4):

From a purely language standpoint, if you've got RxJava in your project you can use any of the combination methods to collate results from multiple Observables. Check out the method list here:

[Rx Combining Methods](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#combining)

It appears that there may not be a direct analog to `whenAny()` but you should be able to achieve something similar to what you are looking for from a reactive standpoint via zip, merge, or one of the other methods.

If you're also thinking specifically about Android UI Rx functionality, the ever prescient Jake Wharton has provided:

[RxBinding Android UI](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding)

Hope this helps!